# Update a column with the data of another column of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

1. titles_downloads
2. title_history

Currently i am saving idtitle_history in titles_downloads as a column. The title_history has a column idtitle which is different from idtitle_history.

I want to change the idtitle_history in my titles_downloads table to idtitle

Example data for title_history table

```
       idtitle_history                 idtitle
            1                             160
            2                             210
            3                             345
```

titles_downloads

```
       iddownloads                      idtitle_history
            1                              1
            2                              2
            3                              3
```

I want to replace the idtitle in this table to 160, 210, 345 ...

Thanks

Comment: I don't get it. Can you give more input?

Comment: @juergen d I want to update the column (idtitle_history) of titles_downloads table with the idtitle column of the titles_history table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
update titles_downloads
inner join title_history 
on title_history.idtitle_history  = titles_downloads.idtitle_history 
set idtitle_history = title_history.idtitle
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE titles_downloads td
JOIN title_history th ON td.iddownloads = th.iddownloads
SET th.iddownloads = td.idtitle
```